# how to select only one cell from the tableviewsection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have used `UITableViewSection`. So i have listed the data which i needed.

But problem in selecting the `UITableViewCell`.

This is my code while selecting the cell.

**this is the screen shot**

[image: **this is the screen shot**]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

    let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:indexPath.section)
    print(model.question)

    // reviewViewModel.question = model.id
    print(model.id)

    let value: Int = model.id
    let string = String(describing: value)
    //let x: Int? = Int(model.id)

    questionViewModel.question_id = string
    questionViewModel.question = model.question

    let optiondatasourcemodel:NH_OptionDataSourceModel = NH_OptionDataSourceModel(array: questionViewModel.tableArray[indexPath.section] as? [String] )
    print(optiondatasourcemodel.dataListArray?.count)

    let optionviewmodel:NH_OptionViewModel = NH_OptionViewModel(withdatasource: optiondatasourcemodel)
    let optionmodel =   optionviewmodel.datafordisplay(atindex:indexPath)

    let modele = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
    print(modele.buttontype)
    optionviewmodel.button = modele.buttontype

    let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell
    print(questionViewModel.questionlist)
    print(questionViewModel.questions)
    print(questionViewModel.answers)

    questionViewModel.question(answer:questionViewModel.question_id!)
    questionViewModel.answer(answer: optionmodel.values!)
    questionViewModel.questionlist(answer: questionViewModel.question!)

    if optionviewmodel.button == "1" {
        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_check.png"), for: .normal)
        self.selected = 1
        questionViewModel.imagename = "1"
    }
    else if optionviewmodel.button == "2" {
        self.selected = 1
        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_check.png"), for: .normal)
        questionViewModel.imagename = "2"
    }
}
```

according to the screenshot there are two question and have two options.From that i need to select only one option .
EX:are u fine:-question
  answer:-yes

just select only one cell.
Once i select yes and i select no option then the data should remove from the array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let optiondatasourcemodel:NH_OptionDataSourceModel = NH_OptionDataSourceModel(array: questionViewModel.tableArray[indexPath.section] as? [String] )
    print(optiondatasourcemodel.dataListArray?.count)

    let optionviewmodel:NH_OptionViewModel = NH_OptionViewModel(withdatasource: optiondatasourcemodel)
    let optionmodel =   optionviewmodel.datafordisplay(atindex:indexPath)

    let modele = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
    print(modele.buttontype)
    optionviewmodel.button = modele.buttontype

    let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell
    print(optionmodel.values)

    questionViewModel.removequestion(question:questionViewModel.question!)
    questionViewModel.removeanswer(answer:optionmodel.values!)
    questionViewModel.removequestionid(removequestionid:questionViewModel.question_id!)


    let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:indexPath.section)
    print(model.question)

    // reviewViewModel.question = model.id
    print(model.id)

    let value: Int = model.id
    let string = String(describing: value)
    //let x: Int? = Int(model.id)

    questionViewModel.question_id = string
    questionViewModel.question = model.question
    questionViewModel.answer = optionmodel.values

    if optionviewmodel.button == "1" {
        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        self.selected = 1
        questionViewModel.imagename = "1"
    }
    else if optionviewmodel.button == "2" {
        self.selected = 1
        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        questionViewModel.imagename = "2"
    }
}
```

this is the code .
But according to this some problem.
Problems:-

1. when i select the second section that means.....
   question:-are u happy 
   for that i selected option as yes.At that time ,i already for first question i have choose one option as yes .And checkbox image will display as click.
   But while i select for next question the checkbox image of first question cell is disappear.How to fix that issues.
2. while selecting the second question option data is not appending in the array.
3. it is appending when i deselect the same cell

So how to fix the problem?

Comment: how to solve the issues

Comment: @Denis how to solve the problem